# using sitemesh with struts2

Tags: java, apache, struts2, sitemesh, opensymphony

Can anyone tell me how to use Sitemesh. I have created a layout page and header and footer. Header and Footer are included from separate pages as static <%@include >. Now I want the middle part "content" to vary keeping header and footer same. How should be the struts.xml and what will be the contents of Layout to include child pages. How will the actions and other links in the pages be so as to have the entire site with same interface.

Comment: thanks... i had solved it myself... but now i want to know what will we do if we have two different columns that change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a minimal example. http://www.benmccann.com/blog/sitemesh-tutorial-with-examples/

In the philosophy of sitemesh, following the 'decorator' pattern, your 'raw' (undecorated) view should be unaware that it's going to be 'decorated' (here, to be 'decorated' can mean 'to be added some common styles  in the head, and some common menu div in the body...'). This extreme decoupling is the beauty of Sitemesh.

More specifically, your Struts2 views code (in your case, the JSP that outputs the result of each action) should be just a full html page (`<html><head>...</head><body>...</body></html>`, but without those 'common' elements.

Sitemesh will catch the raw HTML pages and add the common fragments. This is specified by a 'decorator' (you can have more than one), in your case it would probably be a jsp page (as in the example) and it might itself have some jsp `<%@include >` inside.

Comment: thanks... i had solved it myself... but now i want to know what will we do if we have two different columns that change.

Comment: What do you mean by 'two different columns' ?